# Get previous word from cursor position in summernote

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I need to get previous word from cursor position in `summernote`.

I am getting last word from summernote. but i need get previous word from cursor position.

For example
If the text inside editor is "Hello world. How are you?" and cursor is after "How" and if i press space or enter i need to get "How" word.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.description').summernote({
    height: 300,
    callbacks: {
      onKeyup: function(e){ 
        //32 => space
        //13 => enter
        if(e.which == 32 || e.keyCode == 13){
          var lastword = $('.note-editable').text().replace(/\s+$/, '').split(/(\s|&nbsp;)/).pop();
          console.log(lastword);
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.content{
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.8/summernote-bs4.css" />
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.8/summernote-bs4.js"></script>

  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <textarea class="description"></textarea>
    </div>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: Did you provide [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for better response ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it (just to note - I am not fully aware of your complete requirements. For ex - what if backspace clicked, what to print if first word typed, what if word typed, clicked enter and again typing, etc.):

```js
var inp = document.getElementById('note-editable');
// creating a Set so if space or enter clicked twice, its index wouldn't be captured twice
// could be done without this, but might help the future if need to select different words
var spaces = new Set([0]);

inp.addEventListener("keyup", getWord);

function getWord(e) {
 if(e.which == 32 || e.keyCode == 13){
    // selectionEnd property prints the position of input charecter 
   let spacePos = e.srcElement.selectionEnd;
    spaces.add(spacePos);
    
    let arr = Array.from(spaces);
    let curSpacePos = arr.indexOf(spacePos);
    let prevSpacePos = arr.indexOf(spacePos) - 1;

    var res = Array.from(inp.value);
    console.log(res.slice(arr[prevSpacePos -1], arr[curSpacePos - 1]).join('').trim())   
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="note-editable" type="text">
```